# Need Regexp help PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have for example such string - "7-th Road" or "7th number some other words" or "Some word 8-th word".

I need to get the first occurrence of number and all other next symbols to first occurrence of space.

So for examples above i need such values "7-th", "7th", "8-th".

And then from these matches like "7-th" i need extract only numbers in other operations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some more clear examples, and the code you have so far will go a long way for helping us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex should be `/(\d+)([^\d]+)\s/` and the numbers would resolve to `$1` and the ending characters to `$2`

Sample Code:

```
$string = '7-th Road';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)([^\d]+)\s/', $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

var_dump($result[1]);
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(1) "7"
}

var_dump($result[2]);
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(1) "-th"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is working perfect! Just one question: can this be not related to these suffixes th|st|nd|rd and can be any symbol ?

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you looking for any 7, 9, 15?  Just numbers then?

Comment: There.  Added the extra search for you.

Comment: This regexp - "/(\d+)-?(th|st|nd|rd)/" is good except i dont want to specify in regex these suffixes th|st|nd|rd. There can be any symbols to first occurrence of space. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be i have figured out this myself modifying your example. The regexp i have used: "/(\d+)-?([a-z]+)/"   Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
#(\d+)-?(?:st|nd|rd|th)#
```

[Example](http://xrg.es/#1hue7n5)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get just nums from the text use it:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)[th|\-th]*?/','7-th", "7th", "8-th', $matches);
```

But if you would like to remove 'th' or other just do replacement:

```
preg_replace('/(\d+)[th|\-th]*?/','$1', 'some string')
```

Not sure about the last one...